# Tridion 2013 SP1: Error in CD Website

Tags: content-delivery, 2013-sp1, upgrade

I have recently upgraded from 2011 SP1 HR2 to 2013 SP1. One of my Content Delivery websites is giving an exception, which seems to have the following root cause in the cd_core.log for the website.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Invalid column name 'ENCODING'.

Any idea what causes this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Elena Linhares for putting me on the right track.

I queried the TDS_DB_INFO table in the Tridion_Broker database and discovered that it had not been upgraded yet as it was showing version 6.1.xxx

Upgrading the Tridion_Broker database in the normal way fixed the exception.